# Why can't I get my combobox to show me my ArrayList?

Tags: java, swing, arraylist, jcombobox

I have an arraylist called CountryList, which is a list of countries, and then I have used the code

```
jComboBox1.addItem(countries);
```

to try and add the arraylist into the combobox, but nothing happens, there's no list of countries showing up.

I can't seem to find anywhere that shows why this wouldn't work.

Here is the code that I was told should hold all countries within it:

```
public class CountryList
{

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();

    Locale[] locales = Locale.getAvailableLocales();
    for (Locale locale : locales)
    {
        String iso = locale.getISO3Country();
        String code = locale.getCountry();
        String name = locale.getDisplayCountry();

        if (!"".equals(iso) && !"".equals(code) && !"".equals(name))
        {
            countries.add(new Country(iso, code, name));
        }
    }

    Collections.sort(countries, new CountryComparator());
    for (Country country : countries)
    {
        System.out.println(country);
    }
}
}

class CountryComparator implements Comparator<Country>
{

private Comparator comparator;

CountryComparator()
{
    comparator = Collator.getInstance();
}

public int compare(Country o1, Country o2)
{
    return comparator.compare(o1.name, o2.name);
}
}

class Country
 {

private String iso;
private String code;
public String name;

Country(String iso, String code, String name)
{
    this.iso = iso;
    this.code = code;
    this.name = name;
}

public String toString()
{
    return iso + " - " + code + " - " + name.toUpperCase();
}
}
```

EDIT

```
 for (CountryList country : countries)
    {
        jComboBox1.addItem(country);
    }
```

Comment: perhaps you want to add elements of the `Country` class and not elements of the `CountryList` class

Answer (score 2):

Use a default combo box model.

```
jComboBox1.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(countries.toArray()));
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to add one country at a time, not the whole ArrayList. You can loop through each item and add it to the combobox.

```
for(int i = 0; i < countries.size(); i++) {
        jComboBox1.addItem(countries.get(i));
}
```

Comment: Would that be like this? (Edited OP) I have tried that as well, and nothing happens again

Comment: I get a error when I enter that, it says 

"array required, but found ArrayList<CountryList> found."

Comment: I had made a mistake, the code has been corrected. Try it

Comment: Ugh, it's still blank, and I have no idea why. Do you think it's something to do with the country list?

Comment: I'm not sure. Make sure countries is not empty. Could you post the code where you add data to countries?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/I18N/Getalistofcountrynames.htm


I was told that this class would just hold all the countries somehow, I'm not sure how it works myself. I might obviously just be an idiot and have to implement the countries myself somehow?

Comment: Could you verify that the ArrayList countries is not empty?